# NHibernate Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, nhibernate

I am getting the "Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime" error because from what I can tell I have a record with 0000-00-00 00:00:00.  Now while the data should never be that (it should be null) there are cases when this might happen and I don't want my entire application to crash because of it.  I am using NHibernate and I tried adding change my connection string to allow zero datetime so the connection string configuration looks like:

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">
 Server=localhost;Database=user_system;User ID=root;Password=root;
   Allow Zero Datetime=true;
</property>
```

However I still receive that error.  How can I allow NHibernate to allow zero values for timestamp/datetime/data/time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the `Convert Zero Datetime=true;`, it may help!

Comment: That worked.  I assume that converts 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to NULL?

Comment: Is there any way to have NHibernate do this without the connection string amendment?