# LINQ group by and compare date

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following:

```
    var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var calendarEntry = from item in new CalendarEntryRepository(this.Db).List().Where(x => x.Culture == language.Value)
                  group item by item.ContentObjectId into g
                  let itemMaxDate = g.Where(i => i.StartDate > currentDate).Select(i => i.StartDate).DefaultIfEmpty()
                  let city = g.Select(i => i.City).FirstOrDefault()
                  select new 
                  {
                      ContentObjectId = g.Key,
                      StartDate = itemMaxDate,
                      City = city ?? string.Empty
                  };
```

From CalendarEntryRepository I want to group by ContentObjectId (this works fine). However when i add this line:

```
let itemMaxDate = g.Where(i => i.StartDate > currentDate).Select(i => i.StartDate).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Message = "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value."
```

What i'm trying to do is group by ContentObjectId and then get StartDate that is greater than today.

I'm using entity framwork and MS SQL2008
thanks

Comment: Does DateTime.Now give you a date smaller than 1/1/1753 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Min Value of DateTime in your database has a lower value that the MinValue defined int he culture you used in your App.

Comment: so how do i select what i want?

Comment: Take a look at this question if your db is mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626820/nhibernate-unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime/4626927#4626927

Answer (score 1):

Change the StartDate column in DataBase to data type DateTime2 to support a broader range of dates