# Fluent Nhibernate mysql date problems

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, datetime, fluent-nhibernate

When the datetime field in MySql equals "0000-00-00 00:00:00", NHibernate does not manage to convert it to a .net datetime.

Errormessage:

```
"Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime"
```

How can I configure Fluent NHibernate to cast the value to either null or datetime.min?

Edit:

I have tried this:
[NHibernate Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626820/nhibernate-unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime)
but it does not work. 
Here is my configuration:

```
string connectionString = "Server=SERVER;Port=3306;Database=DB;Uid=USER;Pwd=PASSWORD; Allow Zero Datetime=true;";
        return Fluently.Configure()
          .Database(MySQLConfiguration
                        .Standard
                        .ConnectionString(connectionString)
                        )
         .Mappings(m => 
                        m.FluentMappings
                        .AddFromAssemblyOf<MyMapping>()
                    )
         .BuildSessionFactory()
         ;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626820/nhibernate-unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime

Comment: I have tried this, but without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post I referred has a suggestion about Convert Zero DateTime, I don't see it on your configuration.

Did you try it like this:

```
string connectionString = "Server=SERVER;Port=3306;Database=DB;Uid=USER;Pwd=PASSWORD; Allow Zero Datetime=true;Convert Zero Datetime=true";
        return Fluently.Configure()
          .Database(MySQLConfiguration
                        .Standard
                        .ConnectionString(connectionString)
                        )
         .Mappings(m => 
                        m.FluentMappings
                        .AddFromAssemblyOf<MyMapping>()
                    )
         .BuildSessionFactory()
         ;
```

Comment: Thank you ! I did't see the convert statemenet. Now it works!